# How pop multiples Views of navigationBar and return an object to first page?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to learn how to do an functional block of views.

For example:

I've got a book's list and I want to add a book with a button.

When I push the button --> Launch a Storyboard that it have a navigation controller with 2 or more views. (this create the Book object) and return it to the tableView.

The first table view will receive an object (Book) anymore.

```
Now, I used a view controller with:

    + (AddBookViewController *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static AddBookViewController * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{

        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {

        self = (AddBookViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AddBook" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];


        }
        return self;
    }

- (void)showAddBookVCInController:(UIViewController *)hostVC completion:(AddBookCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    self.compHandler =[completionHandler copy];

    UINavigationController * navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];

    //Show view!
    [hostVC presentViewController:navCtrl animated:YES completion:^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

Any idea or tutorial for this?

Thanks!

Sorry my bad english...

Comment: navigation controller with two views, bit confusing.are u saying nav controller with a view controller having two subviews, what ever i am not clear wid question

Comment: I want to encapsulate the part of "Add Book" to return me a Book object. As if a black box.

Currently I only use a ViewController but I would evolve into multiple views of a branch of storyboard.

First screen: list of my favorite books

Button: Add book. Throws the following storyboard:

- First screen: Category of books.
- Second screen: the books in that category.

And by clicking on one of these books, the main controller receives the book object.

Comment: So from A(list of fav books) > (B)Categories of book > (C)books of chosen category. Now you want C =====bookObject==> A(reload table)

Comment: there are number of ways, you can use notofication (easiest), delegates etc.

Comment: But How I pop multiples views for return to the first page?

Comment: Navigation controller/ tabbar/splitview etc must be root view controllers. however please update your question where you choose a book

Comment: Updated question :) Thank you very much

Comment: I have a shopping list like root, when i add one list, in this list i can add books. then my root is the view of shopping lists...

Comment: does my answer helping you in right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)bookChosen:(Book *)bookObject
{
NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"BOOK_KEY": @(bookObject)};

NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:@"kBookChosenNotification" object:self  userInfo:userInfo];
//here you will write pop if it is Navigation controller flow of presenting view
// OR
//here you will write dismissViewController.... if it was presented using flow of presenting view
}
```

in the view controller where you have list of fav books:

add this in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedChosenBookNotification:) name:@"kBookChosenNotification" object:nil];
```

and implement method receivedChosenBookNotification like below

```
-(void) receivedChosenBookNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"kBookChosenNotification"])
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    Book* bookObject = userInfo[@"BOOK_KEY"];
    NSLog (@"Successfully received chosen book %@", bookObject);
}
}
```

i am not able to understand what you want to do after choosing book, i mean you want to dismiss or you want to pop. It depends on your flow of presenting/pushing view A >> B >>C. Its upto you but in any case you will be  able to receive a book object in view controller A (or say it where you have list of fav books). Hope it helps

Comment: A -> Show -> B -> Show -> C.  Then I create a protocol in C for send to A the book. Thanks again

Comment: you can comment your delegate related stuff and just use above notification, as it being straight forward and less code, and confirm if its working

Comment: Sorry, but i can´t undertand you. Can you told me about "above notification"?

Comment: I use one delegate and [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

Comment: in real world example its like A person home say for example your home and another person say for example its me as guset.

the code in viewDidLoad:[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedChosenBookNotification:) name:@"kBookChosenNotification" object:nil]; is like door bell.

now me as guset come to your home and ring bell, so its like the code bookChoosen.

as soon as bell rang you come to receive me(guest) so as per code it's -(void) receivedChosenBookNotification:(NSNotification*)notification